# How does this C# operator work in this code snippet?

Tags: c#, syntax, operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I found this code snippet on SO (sorry I don't have the link to the question/answer combo)

```
 bool isDir = (File.GetAttributes(source) & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
```

This confuses me because `FileAttributes.Directory` is on both sides of the `==`.

What does the `&` do in this case? I'm not sure how to read this line of code. I'm trying to evaluate whether a path string is a file or a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is using a bit mask to test if a single bit (FileAttributes.Directory) is set.

The values of the enum are powers of two, corresponding to individual bits.

```
    ReadOnly = 1,
    Hidden = 2,
    System = 4,
    Directory = 16,
    Archive = 32,
    Device = 64,
```

If ReadOnly and Directory are set then FileAttributes is equal to 17. The calculation looks like this in binary:

```
File.GetAttributes(source) = 00001001   
FileAttributes.Directory   = 00001000 &
-------------------------------------
                             00001000
```

If the Directory bit was *not* set you'd get zero instead:

```
File.GetAttributes(source) = 00000001   
FileAttributes.Directory   = 00001000 &
-------------------------------------
                             00000000
```

A slightly more concise way to write the expression that gives the same effect is to test against zero:

```
bool isDir = (File.GetAttributes(source) & FileAttributes.Directory) != 0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how C++ handles booleans, but ANSI C would also allow the slightly shorter:  bool isDir = (File.GetAttributes(source) & FileAttributes.Directory);

Answer (score 5):

its doing a Bitwise AND operation. Attributes are stored as bit flags, so it is and'ing those flags together with AttributeFlags.Directory to see if one of the attributes is .Directory.

Good example of Bit Flags here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/wim/archive/2004/04/07/109095.aspx

```
[Flags]
public enum FileAttributes
{
  Archive,        // 0000
  Compressed,     // 0001
  Device,         // 0010
  Directory,      // 0100
  Encrypted,       // 1000
  ...
}
```

Then:

```
 File.GetAttributes(source):  1101
 FileAttributes.Directory:    0100
 (Logical AND):               0100
```

0100 is the same as the directory flag, so we now know that that flag is in the chosen flags of the enum.

Answer (score 2):

It is the [logical & operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx). In this particular example it checks if the [FileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) enumeration has the Directory value, verifying if the string pointed by the `source` variable is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

The single & is a bitwise operator. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=VS.100).aspx

It performs a bitwise AND on the individual bits for the two values. It is used a lot in bit masks.

Answer (score 1):

`&` in this case is a bitwise `and` operator.

Answer (score 1):

It is performing a bitwise flag test - `File.GetAttributes(source)` could return a *number* of flags (in different bits) indicating different properties. The `&` restricts the `1`s to *just* those that are present in `FileAttributes.Directory` (I would expect this to be a single bit). As it happens, this is `16`, i.e. (binary) `..0001000`

if the `source` has `ReadOnly` (=1), `Hidden` (=2) and `Directory` (=16) it would be:

```
...0001011
```

we & with 16

```
...0001000
```

leaving

```
...0001000
```

hence the directory test *passes*.

If instead the source has `System` (=4) and `ReadOnly` (=1) (and not directory) it will be:

```
...0000101
```

we & with 16

```
...0001000
```

leaving

```
...0000000
```

hence the directory test *fails*.

As a side note; an `==` in such a test verifies that **all** the required flags were set (if multiple bits were in the second operand). Another common test is `!= 0`, which tests whether **any** bits were present.

Answer (score 0):

It is the bitwise operator AND.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

The codesnippet performs a bitwise AND between two variables and then compares the value to another variable, placing the result in a bool.

Answer (score 0):

It is bitwise `AND` operation. `FileAttributes` is Flags enum. That means that each bit in numeric value of this enum describes some boolean property of this file and them could be combined.

Answer (score 0):

It's testing whether the flag `FileAttributes.Directory` is set in the enum returned by `File.GetAttributes`. You can read more about how to use flag enums in [this entry on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx#sectionToggle0).

> I'm trying to evaluate whether a path string is a file or a directory.

I'd rather use one of the methods in System.IO, like [`Directory.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx):

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    // it's a directory
} 
else if (File.Exists(path))
{
    // it's a file
}
else
{
   // doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetAttributes returns a flag value, where each bit represents a different Boolean state.  This code uses the bitwise & operator, to turn on the Directory flag, in addition to any other flags returned by GetAttributes.

This appears to have been over-complicated.  This is equivalent to writing:

```
bool isDir = File.GetAttributes(source).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);
```

Or, to test exclusively for the Directory attribute:

```
bool isDir = File.GetAttributes(source) == FileAttributes.Directory;
```

The HasFlag() method is currently a little slow, so a bitwise alternative is faster and uses less resources.  HasFlag is nice for getting a quick and easy response to whether the desired bit in the flag is on or off, without any knowledge of the bit values or binary in general.